# PHP: How to move an array element with an unknown key to end?

Tags: magento2.3, php, array

I have an array which contains list of color values. Consider below array:

```
Array
    (
      [value] => 4
      [label] => red
    )
Array
    (
        [value] => 5
        [label] => pink
    )
Array
    (
        [value] => 6
        [label] => blue
    )
Array
    (
        [value] => 7
        [label] => yellow
    )
Array
    (
        [value] => 8
        [label] => white
    )
Array
    (
        [value] => 9
        [label] => black
    )
```

I want to shift/move color with value **Blue** at the end of the array.

```
Array
(
    [value] => 6
    [label] => blue
)
```

Should it be on last index of array?
**Note:**  The array key is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $array = array(array
    (
        "value" => 4,
        "label" => "red",
    ),
    array
    (
        "value" => 5,
        "label" => "pink",
    ),
    array
    (
        "value" => 6,
        "label" => "blue",
    ),
    array
    (
        "value" => 7,
        "label" => "yellow",
    ),
    array
    (
        "value" => 8,
        "label" => "white",
    ),
    array
    (
        "value" => 9,
        "label" => "black",
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val["label"] == 'blue') {
        $item = $array[$key];
        unset($array[$key]);
        array_push($array, $item);
        break;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

$val["label"] change it on your need

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_filter($array,function($item){return $item['label']!="blue";})+$array;
```

This will merge two arrays non-blue & blue ones. Thereby, moving blue one to the last.